# How to change background color of ngx-ui tooltip?

Tags: angular

I am using the following tooltip:

https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-ui/#tooltip

I want to make the background color green. How can I do this with the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like theming is on their roadmap: https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-ui/issues/53

Though they appear to be under heavy construction and wouldn't hold your breath on getting this provided via the library anytime soon.

Not ideal but you could always override their styles by matching specificity.